# Negative interaction energies for relativistic bound states

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I guess that bound states are treated as poles with infinite lifetime, i.e. precise determination for energy eigenvalues.
But what's left with negative interaction energies, which are connected to bound states in problems solved by the Schroedinger equation? How are the two notions related by a way of approximation?
Furthermore, in the LSZ formalism, field theory excludes bound states. If we assume E>0 for the energy of the interaction, then it is possible to write the Kallen-Lehmann representation of commutators and to give it a physical meaning (also in terms of a normalizing Z between 0 and 1). So, negative interaction energies look like an obstacle for building a collision theory. Can I say the opposite, i.e. that they must be used for a theory of bound states? In which formulation could it be done?
My interest is about a sort of QED in 1+1 dimensions with a 3-valued scalar matter field and a U(1)xU(1)xU(1) gauge field. Is it possible, apart from renormalizability? I hope so. I'd like to construct a theory for collisions and bound states, better if in a path integral formulation. I am grateful for any suggestion, also beyond the subject of this question.
Please forgive me: I am thinking of all that a lot of years after studying theoretical physics...

Comment: The energy is only negative compared to the energy of the constituents separated at infinity. E.g. the energy of the ground state of the hydrogen atom appearing as a pole is the mass of the proton plus electron minus 13.6eV.

Comment: See "minor" changes in the question and its title.  One essential point is that for a scattering theory a positive interaction energy implies Z between 0 and 1.

Comment: Look at Peskin-Schroeder chapter 7.1 (eq 7.8 in particular) and you will see bound states are the norm in the spectral representation, and have no bearing on Z which is determined by one particle states. Also see Weinberg Vol I Chapter 10.2. The stable bound states show up as poles in correlation functions. The hydrogen ground state would be a pole in proton-electron scattering amplitude (off-shell). "Positive interaction energy" would mean an unstable bound state which would be a resonance, not a pole.

Comment: I don't think that bound states are the norm of the spectral representation. Equations at the beginning of cap. 7 in Peskin-Schroeder let them just as a chance. E.g., eq. (7.8) does not show them while it looks like (7.7) do not exclude them. Figures also show "typical" theories, starting from a formulation which contains only a first pole of "1-particle state" and a continuum of "multiparticle state". I don't know what Weinberg says, as I cannot find his book online and I am far from libraries.

Comment: @octonion : see my last comment

Comment: @Arnold Neumaier : see my last comment, I hope you try an answer too. Thanks